# c++ struct trouble, access var within struct

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, auto, assign

ok so below I have a struct in c++:

```
typedef struct tagRECTEx{
 int top;
 int bottom;
 int left;
 int right;
 int width=(this->right-this->left);
 int height;

} RectEx;
```

Now what I would like it to do is that when I declare say RextEx WindowSize; and I assign WindowSize.left=250 and WindowSize.right=300, I want it where WindowSize.width will subtract that for me so when I go and use cout << "Window Width: " WindowSize.width; it will autoamticly subtract right and left which will be 50.

I do not want to do this:

```
WindowSize.width=(WindowSize.right-WindowSize.left);
```

I want that to it for me via:

...
    int width=(this->right-this->left);
...

The only way this will work is if I do this instead:

```
typedef struct tagRECTEx{
 int top;
 int bottom;
 int left=250;
 int right=300;
 int width=(this->right-this->left);
 int height;

} RectEx;
```

but I can't have it do that as they will always change.

Can someone please help me with this as I've been trying to find this online on google for the past 5 hours now.

Thank you

Comment: Implement getter/setter methods

Comment: No, don't "implement" getters/setters. Implement a resize method.

Comment: @jrok A resize method will only help if the properties are private and it cannot be circumvented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways of ensuring that `width` is always "in sync" with the left and right:

- Making `tagRECTEx` immutable, and setting the `width` in the constructor, or
- Adding setter functions for all your variables, and updating `width` every time `left` or `right` is changed, or
- Replacing `width` variable with the `width()` member function, like this:

```
int width() {
    return right-left;
}
```

I prefer this last method, because it is usually more economical, and because it greatly reduces the probability of introducing bugs during maintenance.

Comment: Could you explain me the difference between int width() and my answer bellow? isn't it the same?!

Comment: @Zaibis No, these two answers are very different. Your answer suggests a design where `width` remains incorrect after an assignment of `left` or `right`, until the user of your rectangle call `updateWidth()` themselves. If they forget to make that call, the `width` stays incorrect indefinitely. Calculating the `width` on the fly, on the other hand, never gets "out of sync", because the users are not responsible for calling the update method, and cannot forget to do it.

Comment: yeah but in your case if he want to use width internally, as the struct gives a internal variable width. in your case this one will stay incorrect after your method call. So in your case the user had to do anyway `tagRECTEx.width = tagRECTEx.width();` hadn't he?

Comment: and he explecitly asked for how to set this itnernal value as his given structure looks like this to me. i jsut gave an example that amtches what he asked for.

Comment: @Zaibis I suggested replacing `width` with `width()`, so there's no "internal" `width` to "stay incorrect". There's a very general and important design principle - not storing what can be calculated. OP's struct is in violation of that principle; my answer tries to correct it.

Comment: thank you dasblinkenlight, what you have explained is exactly what I need. Now why couldn't I find this out online?

I've tried looking for following:

Comment: @user2371225 I'm surprised not to find the info on this online. I read about that principle in a book on OO design many years ago, but I couldn't recall which book it was.

Comment: Well I had to get up to get some things done as I was told to. so I didn't finish my last comment but here is the full comment for the one above:

thank you dasblinkenlight, what you have explained is exactly what I need. Now why couldn't I find this out online?

I've tried looking for following:

1. c++ Reference vars in struct
2. c++ Addressing vars within struct
3. c++ Access local variables inside of struct

and etc.

Again thank you all